# Virtual keyboard won't show up after killing explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, windows-explorer, virtual-keyboard

I have an application where I have to restrict users from using Windows functionality, so I do this by killing the `explorer.exe` process, and launching my application in fullscreen.

Everything worked fine until the `Windows 10 1709 (Fall Creators)` update, when the virtual keyboard won't show up anymore (when touching a text-box, or some any other user-input widget).

How can this be fixed (without downgrading the OS)?

The application is written in `WPF`, and it runs on a `Surface 3` tablet.

Comment: Did you check Settings => Devices => Typing, if enabled "Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there's no keyboard attached to your device" (or similar text)?

Comment: @harrymc That's on, as it was before the update.

Comment: Why did I get a -1? Please argument your actions, so I can have a clue on what I did wrong, thanks.

Comment: +1 I also dislike these spurious downvotes. Try to run Keyboard troubleshooter from Control Panel > Troubleshooting > View all.

Comment: @harrymc I can't access Troubleshooting menu while `explorer.exe` is killed. And if I run the keyboard Troubleshooting while the `explorer.exe` process is running there's no problem found. I think it my be related to this problem: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_productivity/windows-10-fall-creators-update-problem-with/0b88f28e-8ff7-427b-9915-66e7438dd39e

Comment: You can access Troubleshooting while explorer is still there and run it after killing explorer, but I doubt that this will help. You might launch yourself the On-Screen Keyboard (osk) in a permanent manner.

Comment: I have the same problem
Windows version 1803 does not work well
And with the last 1809 it gets even worse.

When killing the explorer the virtual keyboard is no longer triggered.

Comment: Note that if all you are doing is killing explorer.exe, a user can easily restart it via the task manager.  You should look into using kiosk mode instead.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Answer (score 0):

Got it, y'all. I don't need to kill explorer anymore so the keyboard shows up.

I'm using Win 10 Home. 
   Here's the fix:   (This will disable all edge swipe, but shouldn't mess with other gesture stuff.)

```
  Open regedit.exe, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI
    (If EdgeUI is not present, Add a new key under Windows, named EdgeUI.)
  Set AllowEdgeSwipe value to zero (0).
    (If AllowEdgeSwipe is not present, add a new DWORD and name it AllowEdgeSwipe, then set to 0.)
```

That's it. You may or may not have to reboot.

Cheers.